# Can I export a document from iOS Freeform to get Vector quality PDF?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, freeform

I updated to iOS 16.4 today and was excited to play with [Freeform](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2022/12/apple-launches-freeform-a-powerful-new-app-designed-for-creative-collaboration/).

I like that my sketches are sharp inside Freeform even when I zoomed up to 400%, but when I exported to PDF and AirDropped the sketch to a nearby iMac, the PDF consisted of a bitmap image, not a vector image - and was pixelated when I zoomed in the equivalent 400%.

**How might I export a higher resolution bitmap or better, a true vector PDF from this app on iOS 16.4?**

Comment: Technically it’s neither.  It’s an infinitely expanding canvas where you can include images both vector and bitmap as well as other objects like pdf and text

Comment: But the Freeform pencil, they draw vector lines, correct? So why can't I export them?

Comment: It's a subtle difference, but I think your actual question is "how can I export Freeform sketches as vectors instead of bitmaps?" You don't actually care about the internals of how they're stored. It could be that they're vectors internally, but impossible to export that way (without a theoretical Jailbreak).

Answer (score 6):

It does look like exporting to PDF does indeed convert to bitmap, and there doesn't seem to be any settings to change this.

You'll need to send [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) that this is a feature you want, and hopefully they'll introduce it.

Comment: Thank you! I have just done that. Oddly enough, it could only let me choose 16.3 as my OS and 16.4 was not listed.

Comment: I've filed feedback. I don't think it will make the slightest difference as Apple famously ignore *bugs* reported by developers on their platform. Feature suggestions from users don't stand a chance.

Comment: @Jason, funny, because I've submitted bug fixed and requests that have been implemented.

Answer (score -4):

You can open the pdf in Inkscape, from there you can export or get the svg files

https://inkscape.org/

Comment: Have you tried to make this work? Does Inkscape allow to convert bitmaps into vector format? Are there specific options needed during the export for this which you could explain here?